# Liferay and Documents and media display portlet

Tags: liferay, customization, document, portlet

I need to have the same functionality provided by the "Documents and Media display" liferay portlet but I would like to use a database other than the liferay with additional custom fields. Is It possible? Is There another portlet to display storing documents in liferay?

Answer (score 0):

Anything is *possible* with Liferay, but this goes against a lot of basic principles of content management.  Most importantly:

- You want to manage content that the Content Management System (CMS) does not own
- You want to use data stored in a format your CMS does not understand or maintain

If you want to use Liferay as your CMS, your best bet is to migrate the documents into the Liferay Document Library and attach your additional content using Custom Fields or 1+ custom service entities that relate back to the document and you maintain.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the first step is what I want. In particular, I would not tie my db documentation in liferay database. But this is difficult if you want to use the "Documents and Display" portlet. Is there a way to customize the Liferay documentatal of asking you to write the information into a table other DLContent etc.? So that I can then index this database with Lucene and if one day I want to access other CMS or other applications to my documents do not have to review the data access logic